# ESLint not sending warning for console.log

Tags: eslint

I have the following .eslintrc...

```
{
  plugins: [
    'markdown',
    'json'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    'ecmaVersion': 2017,
    'sourceType': 'module',
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:vue/essential'
  ]
}
```

To test it I add a console statement to test.js and run `./node_modules/.bin/eslint <folder>/test.js`. I would expect to see something like...

> warning  Unexpected console statement
>   no-console

But instead I see no output. what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work for you. Pay attention to **extends** and **plugins**. I use this structure in my project and everything is ok. And you added `console.log` in **.js** file, `eslint:recommended` will work.

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parserOptions: {
    parser: "babel-eslint",
    sourceType: "module"
  },
  env: {
    browser: true
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/recommended"
  ],
  plugins: [
    "vue" // required to lint *.vue files
  ],
  // add your custom rules here
  rules: {
    "arrow-parens": 0,
    "generator-star-spacing": 0,
    "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? 2 : 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had another eslintrc further down with this...

```
extends: [
  'plugin:vue/strongly-recommended',
  'plugin:vue/recommended'
]
```

I thought this merged the lists for some reason but it actually overrides the list.